# Getting crash in play store console

Tags: android

Play store console is showing crash .Please help,below is log of crash.This is happening is almost all version of android OS.secondly crashes  of my application are decreasing and session are increasing still play store is showing increase in crash rate.
Thanks.

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp (TextView.java:6208)
  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch (KeyEvent.java:3232)
  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent (View.java:7734)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewPager.java:2761)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1410)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent (PhoneWindow.java:2165)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1540)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent (Activity.java:2488)
  at android.support.v7.app.c.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatActivity.java:541)
  at android.support.v7.view.i.dispatchKeyEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
  at android.support.v7.app.f$b.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:319)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent (PhoneWindow.java:2092)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:3897)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:3871)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3436)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3459)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3570)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3467)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3436)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3459)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3467)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3436)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5584)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:5564)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5535)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage (ViewRootImpl.java:3224)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5433)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1268)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi. I am not able to figure out snippet code by which this crash is happening.

Comment: Found the issue. This happens when you press the enter button on the keyboard in an EditText. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47991577/4583267

Answer (score 0):

With the information you're providing, the closest to an answer I can give you is this [Is there a way to track this exception: focus search returned a view that wasn't able to take focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126274/is-there-a-way-to-track-this-exception-focus-search-returned-a-view-that-wasnt) (i.e. search "android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp IllegalStateException"). Good luck.