# java.lang.IllegalStateException: focus search returned a view that wasn't able to take focus

Tags: android, android-launcher, monkey

In Android 7.0,When I run adb shell monkey -p com.android.contacts --throttle 300 -v 10000000,

get log show

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: focus search returned a view that wasn't able to take focus!**

```
--------- beginning of crash
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.launcher3, PID: 4677
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: focus search returned a view that wasn't able to take focus!
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:6413)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2712)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9960)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.launcher3.allapps.AllAppsContainerView.dispatchKeyEvent(AllAppsContainerView.java:525)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.launcher3.dragndrop.DragLayer.dispatchKeyEvent(DragLayer.java:177)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:406)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1798)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3029)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.dispatchKeyEvent(Launcher.java:2385)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:320)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4337)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4308)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3878)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4005)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3886)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4062)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3878)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3886)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3878)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4038)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4199)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2400)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1964)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1955)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2377)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6125)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
01-19 15:46:05.169  4677  4677 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-19 15:46:05.191  2244  3952 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.launcher3/.Launcher
```

Here is part of the source code

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        // Determine if the key event was actual text, if so, focus the search bar and then dispatch
        // the key normally so that it can process this key event
        if (!mSearchBarController.isSearchFieldFocused() &&
                event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            final int unicodeChar = event.getUnicodeChar();
            final boolean isKeyNotWhitespace = unicodeChar > 0 &&
                    !Character.isWhitespace(unicodeChar) && !Character.isSpaceChar(unicodeChar);
            if (isKeyNotWhitespace) {
                boolean gotKey = TextKeyListener.getInstance().onKeyDown(this, mSearchQueryBuilder,
                        event.getKeyCode(), event);
                if (gotKey && mSearchQueryBuilder.length() > 0) {
                    mSearchBarController.focusSearchField();
                }
            }
        }

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }



<com.android.launcher3.ExtendedEditText
                android:id="@+id/search_box_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi"
                android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|textCapWords"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#4c4c4c"
                android:hint="@string/all_apps_search_bar_hint"
                android:textColorHint="@drawable/all_apps_search_hint"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Has anyone encountered such a problem? How is it produced? How to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal crash: Focus search returned a view that wasn't able to take focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614101/fatal-crash-focus-search-returned-a-view-that-wasnt-able-to-take-focus)