# IllegalStateException onKeyUp() crash only in Play Console pre-launch report

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, prelaunch

I am getting this crash only when Pre-Launch Report (PLR) is running on my app. This crash is not happening with real users, but as soon as I upload a new artifact in Play Console, a few minutes later (when the PLR is running) I start seeing crashes in Crashalytics.

Note that I have googled the crash and the [common solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47991577/2456568) to just replace the `EditText`'s `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` but I have no EditText where the crash is happening! Could this be originated when the keyboard is visible in a WebView?

I tried replicating this behavior using Firebase Test Lab but I cannot get it to crash.

Thank you for your time.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: focus search returned a view that wasn't able to take focus!
       at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:9528)
       at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3528)
       at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:14215)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:730)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1949)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:722)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1942)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3998)
       at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:124)
       at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:86)
       at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:142)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:599)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3089)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:588)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6436)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6300)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5742)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5795)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5761)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5917)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5769)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5974)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5742)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5795)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5761)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5769)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5742)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5795)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5761)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5950)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6119)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3821)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:3303)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:3294)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3798)
       at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:143)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

Comment: can you share what types of views are on the screen when the app first opens? AFAIK Firebase Test Lab uses automated scripts to navigate through the app, some element must be capturing input.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. The first screen the FTL sees is a screen with a few buttons (https://ibb.co/LNPw3CC). The follow-up screens all have their `android:imeOptions` set correctly.

Comment: Did you come to a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: Were you able to find any solution?